# How may I retrieve data from an Excel table based on a variable number of criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, database, pivot-table

I have the following salary data for example:

```
Country  State     2012  2013 -> 2027
=======  =====     ====  ====
China    Other     1000  1100
China    Shanghai  1310  1400
China    Tianjin   1450  1500
India    Orissa    1500  1600
```

So now in another Excel sheet I would want an answer to one of the following questions:

1. What is the salary in Shanghai for 2013? (Answer would be 1400)
2. What is the salary in Hubei province for 2012? (Since it is not listed, use "Other" - 1000)
3. What is the average salary in China for 2013? (Answer would be 1333)
4. What is the highest salary in China for 2012? (Answer is Tianjin)

So as in the above order of priority, I would like those numbers in another Excel sheet using some form of query. I considered PivotTables but I was wondering if there is another much better more efficient way of doing this?

I imagine SQL is suited for this but I am not clued up on that. Some Excel functionality is much rather preferred.  Also suggestions on an appropriate format of data for such queries would be appreciated.

Comment: *"I imagine SQL is suited for this but I am not clued up"* - Get clued up on it, it would be a doddle :) If the cells are hard coded, could you not just reference them via a $Sheet$?

Comment: I would gladly learn SQL but I have to share this model with co-workers and yeah they're not very technically inclined or have that kind of time!

Comment: I'd start by unpivoting the data so that you have 4 columns: `Country`, `State`, `Year`, `Salary`. Then make it into a pivot table and use `GETPIVOTDATA()` to pull the data you want.

Comment: Better yet, use database functions!

Answer (score 1):

Your use case is perfect for [Excel's database functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Database-functions-reference-ad87e69b-fc20-4d3d-9d52-d7dc023f5c23). To use them, you'll first need to unpivot your data so that each row corresponds to one observation in your data. This means you will have 4 columns: `Country`, `State`, `Year` and `Salary`.

Then you can use DGET() to get a specific entry in the database and DAVERAGE() to get an average. The criteria for database functions need to be laid out in pairs of cells where the filtering field goes on top and the value to be filtered goes underneath it. Here's a working example:

[image]

The formula for cell I10 is the same as the one for I9, except it uses DAVERAGE instead.

- In `I9` enter `=IFERROR(DGET($B$4:$E$12,$E$4,$G$4:$I$5),"")`
- In `I10` enter `=IFERROR(DAVERAGE($B$4:$E$12,$E$4,$G$4:$I$5),"")`

The `IFERROR()` around it ensures that DGET doesn't show #NUM! when you haven't provided values in all three inputs in row 6. This is because it can't find a single value for the salary if, say, you're not telling it which year to filter on.

Comment: If you'd like to have a flexible number of parameters, you could potentially build the list of criteria for, say, `DAVERAGE()` by using a [dynamic named range](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/DynamicRanges.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I think one way is to name the column - For example, right click on the cell with the value 1400 (salary for Shanghai for 2013) and `define name`

Then, in another cell or just refer to that cell - the beauty of this is it doesn't matter if that cell is moved, it will remain with the content you want.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Dave Rook, that it is the place where you should use SQL.

It is also possible to be done entirely with Excel formulas (what isn't?). This is how:

First of all you will need a way of addressing each column. You have two options for that.

1. First, (like Dave Rook suggested)  straightforward and more "beautiful", is to define named ranges. Just be sure, that each named range is big enough to contain all future records (or use some sort of dynamic named range). Unfortunately it require some clicking for each column, so it doesn't scale when you have 100 columns.
2. The other option (which I prefer for heavy-duty computations) is to generate the column range addresses strings using e.g. `=ADDRESS(ROW(C3);COLUMN(C3);4;;"sheet1") & ":" & ADDRESS(ROW(C3)-1+$A$2;COLUMN(C3);4)` for accessing data on column `C` with number of records stored in cell `A2`. Then you address the range by use of `INDIRECT()` formula everywhere, when you would normally paste the named range from method 1.

Once all your columns (fields) are named ranges, you can perform all sort of lookup and reference tasks on them.

For instance: to identify the number of record which contains the word "Shanghai" you would use `=MATCH("Shanghai";State;0)`, where `State` is the named range for the column "State".

Once you have the record number (let's say it is in cell `X10`, you can get information about Salary with `=INDEX(Salary;X10)`.

All sorts of tasks are possible in Excel formulas; e.g. you can create a list of *unique* values (or values that match certain criteria), you can compute any form of sum/average. You can even sort them (yes!).

Please note, that in my locale I use semicolon `;` as argument separator (not comma). English-speaking countries usually use `,`, and in that case to use my formulas you would need to replace all `;` -> `,`.

Comment: I guess you meant `MATCH` and not `MATH`? and also I think it should  be noted that the use of semicolon or comma depends on the locale - usually it's a comma.

Answer (score 0):

With some preparation, this can also be easily done in Excel too.
(Although might be easier and more natural with SQL).

The preparation: use named ranges as @Adam suggested - `country` for the Country, `state` for the State, and I also named each of the year in this format `year2012`.

Then you can create your answers sheet

```
     A              B         C         D
1 salary in     Shanghai    2013    =IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("year"&C1),MATCH(B1,state,0)),INDEX(INDIRECT("year"&C1),MATCH("Other",state,0)))
2 salary in     Hubei       2012    =IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("year"&C2),MATCH(B2,state,0)),INDEX(INDIRECT("year"&C2),MATCH("Other",state,0)))
3 average       China       2013    =AVERAGEIF(country,B3,INDIRECT("year" & C3))
4 highest       China       2012    {=INDEX(state,MATCH(MAX(IF(country=B4,INDIRECT("year"&C4))),INDIRECT("year"&C4),0))}
```

Each of these lines are dynamic, so you can change your 'questions' as required.
The important thing to notice is that the 4th (highest) formula is Array Formula which requires the use of `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` when entering it.

p.s. Your answer to the 3rd question is wrong, the average salary in China in 2013 should be 1333.

Answer (score 0):

Go for this vba aproach, It should work without too much tweaking. Error handling could be updated, tho:

```
Private Sub get_money(byval country as string, byval city as string, byval year as string)
    if country == "" then country == "nope" end if
    if city == "" then city =="nope" end if
    if year == "" then year =="nope" end if
    if autofiltermode = true then autofiltermode = false

    dim all_columns as double
    all_columns = thisworkbook.activesheet.range("A1").currentregion.columns.count
    with thisworkbook.activesheet
        for cell_position = 3 to all_columns
            if .cells(1,cell_position) == year
                year_to_filter = cell_position
                cell_position = all_columns
            end if
        next cell_position
        .Range(.cells(1,1), .cells(1,all_columns)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=country, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .Range(.cells(1,1), .cells(1,all_columns)).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=city, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .Range(.cells(1,1), .cells(1,all_columns)).AutoFilter Field:=cell_position, Criteria1:=year, Operator:=xlFilterValues 
    end with      
end sub
```